# How to search for nuget package of particular header file

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

Hi I am pretty new to coding projects and I want to import this script to run it in my project

I have tried including its header but still it kept showing error I am including the link can anyone tell me how to run the script so that I can finish my project.

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/blob/main/src/ArcGISRuntime.Samples.Shared/Managers/DataManager.cs

Comment: The home [page](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet) in github tells you how to use the samples, and you have to install the ArcGIS SDK first.

Comment: Hi i just need the datamanager.cs script from it and in the samples shown here they have used a header file which means there is a possiblity of importing without running it r8, the problem with installing is i am using a virtual box Mac which makes it hard to run anything,https://developers.arcgis.com/net/wpf/sample-code/animate-3d-graphic/